# VBA 1004 Runtime Error Introduced After Restarting Computer

Tags: vba, excel

I have been attempting to write a VBA Script that can parse out other files for specific data that I can then input into the currently opened Excel Workbook.  The files are all Tab Deliminated and are found in a different directory than the currently opened workbook.  The code below worked until I restarted my computer, and now I always get a "1004 Runtime Error."  This error always occurs when the code hits the "select.TextToColumns" line of the DeliminateCSV subroutine.  The error occurs because the program is selecting empty cells.  I believe the program is selecting the currently open workbook which is currently empty.  I believed maybe my CSV variable in ParseSummaryReport was opening the wrong workbook, but I watched it in Debug mode and it seemed to have the correct filepath to open.  Any ideas whats going on?

```
Option Explicit
    Sub PopulateSpreadSheet()

    Dim fso             As Object
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.folder
    Dim startingFolder As Scripting.folder
    Dim iNumFiles As Integer

        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        'Get path of current workbook
        fPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(fPath)

        'Move up one directory
        Set startingFolder = fsoFolder.ParentFolder

        iNumFiles = 0

        Call RecursiveFileCheck(startingFolder, iNumFiles)

    End Sub

    Sub ParseSummaryReport(ByRef i As Integer, fileName As String)
    Dim CSV As Workbook
    Dim Excel As Excel.Application

    'Data From CSV To Put In Tracking
    Dim ES_Number As String
    Dim custodian As String
    Dim EDoc_Size As Double
    Dim Email_Size As Double

    Set Excel = New Excel.Application

    'Set CSV = Excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Set CSV = Excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName, , , , , , , , "    ")



    'Deliminate the CSV File
    'Call DeliminateCSV(CSV)


    Call CSV.Close(False)

    End Sub

    Sub RecursiveFileCheck(ByRef folder As Scripting.folder, ByRef iNumFiles As Integer)
    Dim nextFolder As Scripting.folder
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim nextFile, files, subFolders

    Set files = folder.files
    Set subFolders = folder.subFolders

    'Search through all the files in this folder
    For Each nextFile In files

        'Check if this is one of the files we want
        If nextFile Like "*_SummaryReport.csv" Then

            'Summary Report Found, Parse It
            fileName = nextFile
            Call ParseSummaryReport(iNumFiles, fileName)
        End If

    Next nextFile

    'Search through all the subfolders recursively
    For Each nextFolder In subFolders
        Call RecursiveFileCheck(nextFolder, iNumFiles)
    Next nextFolder

    End Sub

    Sub DeliminateCSV(ByRef wrkBook As Workbook)
        With wrkBook
            Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
With wrkBook
...
End with
```

then you should add a "." in front of any properties or methods belonging to that workbook

```
With wrkBook
    Columns("A:A").Select             
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1")...
End With
```

should be

```
With wrkBook
    .Columns("A:A").Select             
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1")...
End With
```

You don't need to select though:

```
.Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1")...
```

will also work

Comment: Thanks, I havent used the with statement much.

Comment: @user1476050 there is a holo checkbox next to each answer, ticking it lets everyone know this question has a answer that is the solution, marking correct answers gives you a couple of points too:)